# How can I use for loop to make new columns and extract files to answer questions 3 and 4?

Tags: r, for-loop

You can find questions number 3 and 4 here

[image]

This is a small part from the data files just to get an idea:

```
"1.08E+03  -4.00E-06
1.08E+03  -5.60E-06
1.09E+03  -3.33E-06
1.09E+03  -4.60E-06
1.10E+03  -3.33E-06"
```

Here is what I tried to do:

```
library(zoo)

#Reading the file in data frame
dat_10 <- read.table(text="1.08E+03  -4.00E-06
```

1.08E+03  -5.60E-06
1.09E+03  -3.33E-06
1.09E+03  -4.60E-06
1.10E+03  -3.33E-06", header = F)

```
#Changing the name of the columns, for a smoother working environment
colnames(dat_10) <- c("Time", "Runoff")

#Replacing the 0 values in the Time column with NA to remove it
dat_10["Runoff"][dat_10["Runoff"] == 0] <- NA
dat_10 <- na.omit(dat_10)

#Multiplying the Runoff column to get positive numbers
dat_10$Runoff <- dat_10$Runoff * -1

#Creating the new column with the required moving average

for(i in c(3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 20)){
dat_10$moving_average <- rollmean(dat_10$Runoff, k = i, fill = NA)
}

#Removing the second column since the requested results need only the time and the moving average
ten_win20<- dat_10[, -2]

#Renaming the columns
colnames(ten_win20) <- c("Time in seconds", "Moving average of runoff")

#Saving the file
write.table(ten_win20, file="10_win20.dat")
```

Comment: So where are you seeing a problem?

Comment: @IRTFM the for loop command I have created does not create multiple columns and I do not know how to do that. I also don't know how to export the 70 files according to the attached exercice.

Comment: I edited the question body to make it a MCVE. You now need to show the output that is not meeting your specifications. (Note that I needed to edit out the backslashes in the leading numerical values in each row. If those backslashes are in your original, that may be a problem. And if they were there you should ahve reported the error message.)